# Auto-Resize Table with a dependence to a textfield

Tags: php, html, css

i would like to get a resizeable textfield. You can see the Table and i have there a Input Text in HTML. The content depends on a calculation and i don't know how long the String would be. Is it possible to auto-resize the width of the input type "text" in a dependence to the represented content in the field?

Thanks for your help.

Here you can see my sample.

```
       <table class="returnTable" style="overflow: auto">
                <tr>
                    <td class="fett">Kalkulierter Hash-Wert:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" style="overflow: auto; resize: both" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['hashWert'])){echo $_POST['hashWert'];}  ?>"</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

**PHP**

```
$size = strlen($_POST['hashWert']);
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" size="<?php echo $size; ?>" value="<?php echo $_POST['hashWert']; ?>">
```

P.S. perhaps you have to adjust the size a little bit, according to your font-size etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate width of the text. This looks promising: [Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)

when you know text width, you can set width of your :

```
var el = document.getElementById("MyInputText");
el.syle.width=width;
```

Don't forget to give your input proper ID so it can be found by javascript.

Comment: I have no idea about the width of the text. It must be completely responsive. Is there a way without JS ?